# Access - How to calculate average days between orders (without a cursor)

Tags: date, ms-access, cursor, average

I want to create a query in access returning the average days between orders.
The table structure is:
**Table name:**

```
 Orders
```

**table columns:**

```
idOrder (integer)
 idClient (integer)
 OrderDate (date in format dd/mm/yyyy)
 OrderAmount (money)
```

A simple query to the table would return this:

```
1 1131 01/01/2015 $235
2 1145 02/01/2015 $11
3 1131 03/01/2015 $256
4 1131 04/01/2015 $300
5 1146 05/01/2015 $25
6 1145 10/01/2015 $15
7 1145 20/01/2015 $4
8 1131 21/01/2015 $45
```

in this example,

```
client 1131 has orders on the days: 01/01/2015; 03/01/2015; 04/01/2015; 21/01/2015
client 1145 has orders on the days: 02/01/2015; 10/01/2015; 20/01/2015
client 1146 has orders on days: 05/01/2015
```

i would like to create a query returning for each client the average days between orders:

```
1131 5
1145 6
1146 null
```

If it would be sql server, I would use a cursor, but in Access, i dont know how to do it.

Any help?

Comment: For reference, somewhat equivalent in Access VBA is a RecordSet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't need a cursor in SQL Server.
Having said that, try the below query.
If a customer placed one order, logically the result should be 0 (zero), not null.
Null should reflect any customers that did no place any orders.

```
SELECT Orders.idClient, (Max(Orders.OrderDate)-Min(Orders.OrderDate))/Count(*) AS [Days between orders]
FROM Orders
GROUP BY Orders.idClient
```

Comment: Thanks Rene, it seems to be working fine. So, the magic is in doing `max(orders.date) - min (orders.date)/count(*)` and grouping by **client**; am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Create a query like this:

```
Select
    idClient,
    Avg(DaysPast) As AverageOrderDays
From    
    (Select 
        idClient, 
        DateDiff("d",
                (Select Max(T.[Purchase Week]) 
                From Orders As T 
                Where T.idClient=Orders.idClient 
                And T.[Purchase Week] < Orders.[Purchase Week]),
            [Purchase Week]) AS DaysPast
    From 
        Orders) As OrderDays
Group By
    idClient
```